# qsort a double pointer pointing to an array of struct pointers

Tags: c, qsort

Hi I am very new in learning C programming language and have trouble understanding this problem. I want to qsort a double pointer pointing to an array of struct[person] pointers. I need to sort the struct pointer according to multiple criteria. (age in ascending order, both name and height should be in descending order). I wonder if my syntax is correct in the following comparison function and qsort call.

```
    struct person {
        int age;
        float height;
        char name[20];
    };
    struct person **arr = malloc(sizeof(struct person)*10);
    ..... this part is just initialisation

    qsort(arr, 10,sizeof(struct person*), compareFunction);

    int compareFunction(const void *a, const void *b){
        struct person* p1 = (struct person*) a;
        struct person* p2 = (struct person*) b;

        if(p1 - >age > p2-> age){
            return 1;
        } else if (p1 -> age < p2 <-age){
            return -1;
        }
        if (strcmp(p1 - >name, p2 ->name)<0){
            return 1;
        } else if (strcmp(p1-> name , p2->name)>0){
            return -1;
        }
        if (p1 -> height < p2 ->height){
            return 1;
        } else if (p1 - > height > p2 ->height){
            return -1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: `struct person p1 = (struct person*) a;` cannot be correct. You can't convert a pointer to non-pointer implicitly

Comment: Any compiler will tell you whether your syntax is correct. No need to interact with people in this case.

Comment: post your qsort function prototype along with how you are declaring doubleoointer

Comment: The question is incomplete, as relevant parts of the code are missing. Though it is not possible to give a serious answer. One would need to guess, what I won't do.

Comment: We *at least* need to know how `doublePtr` is defined and set.

Comment: sorry for incomplete code. I just added some more code into it. my code is valid in C but somehow couldn't do what I want. I want to sort the order of the structs.

Comment: Post your full code.

Comment: "*what I want*" and what do you get?

Comment: "*this part is just initialisation*" which could be done wrongly as well.

Comment: "*`struct person **arr = malloc(sizeof(struct person)*10);`*": why do you allocate to a **pointer-to-pointer**-to-struct a block of structs? The malloc as shown requiered a `struct person *arr = ...` on the left-hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

**->** used to access a structure member with structure pointer.

```
structure_pointer->structure_member
```

where as for structure variable we use '.' operator.

```
structure_variable.structure_member
```

your compareFunction can be modified to

```
int compareFunction(const void *a, const void *b){
    if(a->age > b->age){
        return 1;
    } else if (a->age < b->age){
        return -1;
    }
    if (strcmp(a->name, b->name)<0){
        return 1;
    } else if (strcmp(a->name, b->name)>0){
        return -1;
    }
    if (a->height < b->height){
        return 1;
    } else if (a->height > b->height){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Those casts are not needed. With C a `void`-pointer is *implicitly* converted to/from any other pointer-type.

Comment: I can't compile if those casts are not in there.

Comment: My mistake I forgot to replace p1 with a and p2 with b. As we are not typecasting we don't need p1 and p2 anymore

Comment: "*I can't compile if those casts are not in there.*" you then most likely are using a C++ compiler, not a C compiler.

Comment: I updated the code without p1 and p2. If you are trying with new code only, can  you paste your error here.